# Effect of Force(ex:Ship movement) on objects(nodes) deployed in the sea or ocean

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, flow, oceanography

I am looking for a mathematical model describing the motion of nodes deployed in sea due to movement of ship(a Force) or due to water current. I came across the drag equation which is used to calculate the force of drag experienced by an object due to movement through a fully enclosing fluid. I am still researching for a more robust function which would help me to simulate the movement of the node under the influence of the above described force. So, I am eager to know other methods which would answer my above question.